# Accordions are opening together

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

[image: accordions are opening together]

As you can see in the image, when I open one accordion, the accordion beside it opens as well. I think its the CSS that's causing the issue, but I'm not sure I expected the accordion to open by itself, not with the accordion beside it, it seems as if the JavaScript is controlling the max height of the accordion beside it too.

---

Here is the code:

```js
const accordionItemHeaders =
  document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-header");

accordionItemHeaders.forEach((accordionItemHeader) => {
  accordionItemHeader.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    accordionItemHeader.classList.toggle("active");
    //animation
    const accordionItemBody = accordionItemHeader.nextElementSibling;
    if (accordionItemHeader.classList.contains("active")) {
      accordionItemBody.style.maxHeight =
        accordionItemBody.scrollHeight + "px";
    } else {
      accordionItemBody.style.maxHeight = 0;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.accordion-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.accordion-card {
  background-color: rgba(182, 210, 253, 0.041);
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 30vw;
  max-width: 385px;
  min-width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(153, 196, 239, 0.121);
  position: relative;
}

.accordion-header {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.841);
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem 0.8rem 1.3rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion-body {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.accordion-body-content {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.658);
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  padding: 0.8rem 1rem 0.8rem 1.3rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(153, 196, 239, 0.053), rgba(153, 196, 239, 0.201), rgba(153, 196, 239, 0.053)) 1;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
}

.accordion-header::after {
  content: '\003E';
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
  transition: ease-in 0.3s;
}

.accordion-header.active::after {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: ease-in 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion-wrapper">
  <div class="accordion-card">
    <div class="accordion-header">Card 1</div>
    <div class="accordion-body">
      <div class="accordion-body-content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos aliquid sint voluptatum deserunt alias iusto excepturi pariatur odio
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="accordion-card">
    <div class="accordion-header">Card 2</div>
    <div class="accordion-body">
      <div class="accordion-body-content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque nesciunt vero sunt. Ad eveniet maiores quidem quis id animi
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="accordion-card">
    <div class="accordion-header">Card 3</div>
    <div class="accordion-body">
      <div class="accordion-body-content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque nesciunt vero sunt. Ad eveniet maiores quidem quis id animi
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="accordion-card">
    <div class="accordion-header">Card 4</div>
    <div class="accordion-body">
      <div class="accordion-body-content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque nesciunt vero sunt. Ad eveniet maiores quidem quis id animi
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="accordion-card">
    <div class="accordion-header">Card 5</div>
    <div class="accordion-body">
      <div class="accordion-body-content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque nesciunt vero sunt. Ad eveniet maiores quidem quis id animi
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="accordion-card">
    <div class="accordion-header">Card 6</div>
    <div class="accordion-body">
      <div class="accordion-body-content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque nesciunt vero sunt. Ad eveniet maiores quidem quis id animi
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This [article](https://www.itzami.com/blog/how-to-build-an-accordion-with-javascript) will solve your problem!

Answer (score 2):

This is caused because `display: flex` uses `align-items: stretch` as default value which causes other elements in the row to fill whenever any enlarges the parent they all are contained in. Please set it to `flex-start` which will prevent this from happening, like this:

```
.accordion-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 25px;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```